# Any formula is logically equivalent to a formula with all terms of height ≤ 1.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

i read the book of title "A First Journey Through Logic" written by Martin Hils at page 73.

the problem is i don't understand given the proof's procedures how this process shows that any formula is logical equivalent with formula having therm height equal or less than 1?

I find it challenging to understand how this proof unfolds and, at the same time, I struggle to comprehend how comparing the lengths of formulas demonstrates their logical equivalence.

the height's def in this book may be a number of connective operations, so atomic formula's height is zero.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

The "*height*'s def in this book may be a number of connective operations"; this is the height of a *formula*. Terms have no connectives.

For a term, the [height (or depth)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(logic)#Operations_with_terms) means in a nutshell the number of function symbols: thus $h=0$ for variable and constants, and so on.

The proof consider the atomic formula $Rt_1 \ldots t_n$ and apply induction.

The machinery is to consider terms from right to left (lexicograpich order) and reduce the height one-by-one. Assuming that we have already worked on terms $t_{m+1}, \ldots, t_n$ we have to "reduce" the previous ones.

Consider $t_i=f_i(s_{i,1} \ldots s_{i, k_{i}})$: the terms $s$'s have height one less that that of $t_i$.

Thus we use new variables $y_{i,j}$ and we "equate" them to the $s$'s terms using the formula: $y_{i,j}=s_{i,j}$ whose terms have height less than that of $t_i$.

The *equivalence* is simply:

> $\varphi(t) \leftrightarrow (\varphi [y/t] \land y=t)$.

Comment: thanks your comment. i understand u r comment original induction process move 1,,.n,n+1 whereas this proof's induction procedure moves n,..,m+1,m,...,1, but i can't still understand yours mention "Consider ti=fi(si,1…si,ki)
: the terms s's have height one less that that of t.".

Comment: The reason each si has a height one less than ti, as mentioned earlier, is in accordance with the definition of height being the number of function symbols. In the form ti=f(si,1,...,si,k), ti represents the result of applying a function to a tuple composed of ki si elements. Therefore, each si, being a component before the application of the function, has a height one less than ti?

Comment: and in ψ, Why does replacing si with yi in an arbitrary formula φ make it logically equivalent?

Comment: @유준상 - Yes, if $t=f(s)$ has height n, when we remove the function f the term s has height n-1. Then, generalize it.

Comment: NO, $\varphi[y/t]$ is not equiv to $\varphi$ but $\varphi [y/t] \land y=t$ is.